# SQL - WHERE clause on each SET command in UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to create an SQL query in PHP to update a table.
Is it possible to have a different `WHERE` clause for each affected row?

eg something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET val=X WHERE someproperty = 1,
SET val=Y WHERE someproperty = 2
```

etc?

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot have multiple WHERE clauses for any SQL statement, however you can use a CASE statement to accomplish what you are trying to do. Another option that you have is to execute multiple UPDATE statements.

Here is a sample using the CASE statement:

```
UPDATE table
SET val = (
    CASE someproperty
        WHEN 1 THEN X
        WHEN 2 THEN Y
        ELSE val
    END
);
```

Here is a sample using multiple UPDATE statements:

```
UPDATE table SET val=X WHERE someproperty = 1;
UPDATE table SET val=Y WHERE someproperty = 2;
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can with a CASE statement.

```
UPDATE table
SET val = CASE someproperty  
           WHEN 1 THEN x 
           WHEN 2 THEN y
           ....
          ELSE
           val
          END
```

Now, there is concern that one `CASE` statement is less readable when compared to several `UPDATE` statements.  There is a valid argument here.  For example, when 1000 rows are being updated, it just feels and looks better to use several `UPDATE` statements rather than 1000 different conditions to a single `CASE`.

However, sometimes a CASE statement is more appropriate. If, for example, you are updating rows based on some trait, say the even or odd nature of a field's value the table, then a `CASE` statement is a wonderfully concise and maintainable way to update rows in the table without having to resort to a huge number of `UPDATE` statements that all share a specific type of logic.  Take this for example:

```
UPDATE table
SET val = CASE MOD(someproperty, 2)  
           WHEN 0 THEN x 
           WHEN 1 THEN y
          END
```

This expression takes the modulus of someproperty and, when 0 (even), assigns value x to val and, when 1 (odd), assigns value y to val.  The greater the volume of data being updated by this statement, the cleaner it is compared to doing so by multiple `UPDATE` statements.

In short, `CASE` statements are sometimes just as readable/maintainable as `UPDATE` statements.  It all depends on what you are trying to do with them.

**EDIT**: Added the ELSE clause to be extra safe.  The OP may be interested in updating only specific rows so the rest should remain as they prior to the UPDATE.

**EDIT**: Added a scenario where the `CASE` statement is a more effective approach than multiple `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: This is technically accurate, and answers your question.  However, you may want to consider read-ability and support-ability when deciding what coding practice to use.  I recommend breaking out into multiple insert statements as others have noted unless there is a performance issue that you are trying to solve.

Comment: People seem deathly afraid of CASE statements or other ANSI-friendly database functions for some reason.  This is about the third or fourth time today that someone has quoted the readability factor.  Conciseness makes for readability too, and depending on the nature of the UPDATE a single statement may be more readable with a switch rather than multiple UPDATE statements.  It really does depend on the problem at hand and the experience of those maintaining its solution.

Comment: @Jay: I've added to this post cases where a single CASE statement may be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Make it two updates:

```
UPDATE table SET val=X WHERE someproperty = 1;
UPDATE table SET val=Y WHERE someproperty = 2;
```

On second thought, you could use sub-queries or the case statement...

```
UPDATE table SET val= ( case when someproperty = 1 then X when someproperty = 2 then Y else val END )
```

You may need to make that a sub query like this:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET val = ( select CASE when someproperty = 1 then X when someproperty = 2 then Y ELSE val END from table t2 where t1.primarykey = t2.primary key )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET VAL CASE SOMEPROPERTY WHEN 1 THEN X WHEN 2 THEN Y END
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact and easily scaleable way:

```
UPDATE table1 SET val=ELT(FIND_IN_SET(someproperty, '1, 2'), X, Y);
```

make the query this way:

```
$condition = array(1, 2);
$newvals = array('X', 'Y');
$query = "UPDATE table1 SET val=ELT(FIND_IN_SET(someproperty, '". implode(',', $condition). "', ". implode(', ', $newvals). ")";
```

Use prepare_query to avoid SQL syntax errors if you deal with string values.

Comment: Anyway, use 1-query update instead of multiple as in the response you've chosen.