# Updating table using wildcard in Switch case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use an Oracle SQL update statement using a 'SWITCHED' case statement as mentioned below:

```
update MY_TABLE SET STATE_ABBREVIATION=
(CASE STATE 
WHEN 'MAHARASHTRA' THEN 'MH'
WHEN 'ASSAM' THEN 'AS'
WHEN 'HIMACHAL%' THEN 'HP'
...
ELSE 
STATE
END
);
```

I got this clue from the thread [SQL - WHERE clause on each SET command in UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421116/sql-where-clause-on-each-set-command-in-update)

The issue is that the wildcard fields are not functioning as expected. The State column may values like 'Himachal Pradesh' as well as 'HimachalPradesh'.

I also searched https://community.oracle.com/thread/290198 ,one of the answers there used a '**searched** case' which works fine..
..

```
CASE 
(WHEN STATE LIKE 'ANDHRA%' THEN 'AP'
 WHEN STATE LIKE 'HIMACHAL%' THEN 'HP'
END
```

How can we achieve this in the SWITCHED case style ?
I also tried

```
update MY_TABLE SET STATE_ABBREVIATION=
(CASE STATE 
WHEN 'MAHARASHTRA' THEN 'MH'
WHEN 'ASSAM' THEN 'AS'
WHEN LIKE 'HIMACHAL%' THEN 'HP'
...
ELSE 
STATE
END
);
```

This too did not work.

> (SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword").

Comment: these two swich case forms can not be mixed.

Comment: @ibre5041 There s no problem using `=` and `LIKE` operator in the **CASE** expression

Comment: @LalitKumarB, the solutions mentioned below is same as that mentioned in https://community.oracle.com/thread/290198, which I had referred to in the question. I had no issue substituting operators '=' with 'LIKE' there. My query is if I would be able to use such operators in the switch case style above, which works normally with 'WHEN' ..'THEN' combination, but does not allow me to use a 'LIKE' operator referring to the STATE. If this is feasible, please point out.

Comment: @LalitKumarB,In other words, I want to avoid keying in WHEN STATE =' '  THEN ' ' or when STATE LIKE ' '  THEN ' ' a hundred times. Seems like there is no direct solution. I have to live with it, if data is not consistent throughout (Himachal Pradesh and HimachalPradesh for e.g.). Could you help out with this? Any alternate workaround would also help me out. Thanks for your elaborate explanation below.

Comment: @Vvn To use multiple conditions using different operators as in your case, only searched case would work.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Exactly :-( And that was clear to me seeing the syntax diagram posted by Jens Schauder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the searched version in all cases.

See the [syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Fildor The essential part is in the sentence above. And I don't know how to include (with resonable effort on my side) a syntax diagram in the answer.

Comment: @JensSchauder Your answer is wrong because it is possible to mix both operations. See my answer.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I noticed, that your answer is in contradiction to mine. Yet I don't see how I misinterpreted the syntax diagram. Maybe this is a version thing? The docs I linked to a version 10.2. Which version did you use?

Comment: @JensSchauder You have misunderstood the syntax for searched case. See my previous answer regarding the explanation of the two syntax http://stackoverflow.com/a/28558926/3989608 Serached doesn't mean you are restricted with the use of operator. Searched case expression infatc gives you the flexibility to check multiple conditions from left to right, Oracle uses short-circuit evaluation. OP's question is not about mixing the two syntax, rather use of two different operators, which Oracle allows to do. In OP's case, only searched case would work.

Comment: @JensSchauder FYI, my Oracle version is `12.1.0.2`, and I know this would work on all the versions since the CASE statement was introduced. Perhaps you might want to execute and check.

Comment: Now, I understand what is going on, although my answer actually is correct, but easy to misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` in all your conditions as there is no difference between `= 'aaaa'` and `LIKE 'aaaa'` in terms of output

```
update MY_TABLE SET STATE_ABBREVIATION=
(CASE
WHEN STATE LIKE 'MAHARASHTRA' THEN 'MH'
WHEN STATE LIKE 'ASSAM' THEN 'AS'
WHEN STATE LIKE 'HIMACHAL%' THEN 'HP'
...
ELSE 
STATE
END
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem using `=` and `LIKE` operator in the CASE expression.

For example,

**Table**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM(
  2  WITH DATA(state) AS(
  3  SELECT 'MAHARASHTRA' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'ASSAM' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'HIMACHAL PRADESH' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'ANDHRA PRADESH' FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT * FROM DATA);

Table created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

STATE
----------------
MAHARASHTRA
ASSAM
HIMACHAL PRADESH
ANDHRA PRADESH

SQL>
```

**CASE statement**

```
SQL> SELECT CASE
  2  WHEN state = 'MAHARASHTRA' THEN 'MH'
  3  WHEN state = 'ASSAM' THEN 'AS'
  4  WHEN state LIKE 'HIMACHAL%' THEN 'HP'
  5  ELSE state
  6  END
  7  FROM t;

CASEWHENSTATE='M
----------------
MH
AS
HP
ANDHRA PRADESH
```

**UPDATE statement**

```
SQL> UPDATE t
  2    SET state = (
  3                 CASE
  4                 WHEN state = 'MAHARASHTRA' THEN 'MH'
  5                 WHEN state = 'ASSAM' THEN 'AS'
  6                 WHEN state LIKE 'HIMACHAL%' THEN 'HP'
  7                 ELSE state
  8                 END
  9                );

4 rows updated.
```

**Test case**

```
SQL> select * from T;

STATE
----------------
MH
AS
HP
ANDHRA PRADESH

SQL>
```

So, update is done successfully.